# Why does string::begin exist?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdstring

If I understand correctly, `string::begin` returns the pointer to the first element in the string. If that is the case, why wouldn't we just use  `&str` to get the pointer.

Are there situations where using `begin` is better, or have I misunderstood it's function?

Comment: `std::string::begin` returns an iterator to the first element - not necessarily a pointer, but often it is implemented by being a simple pointer to the first element. Having said that, it is important to note that given `std::string str`, `&str` is **not** a pointer to the first character (nor it's an iterator to one). It's a pointer to the string. Pointer to the string is **not** a pointer to the first character.

Comment: I'm too tired to make a proper answer, but a good answer might also mention the usefulness of the `begin` and `end` pair in calling standard library methods, since OP seems new enough not to know.

Comment: OP might means `&str[0]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, `string::begin` returns the pointer to the first element in the string.

No, it returns an *iterator* to the first element in the string. It helps make `std::string` compatible with language constructs (think templates) designed to work with standard containers.

> why wouldn't we just use `&str` to get the pointer.

For one thing, that is not the address of the first element of the string? Assuming `str` is a variable of type `std::string`, that would be the address of an object that, among other things, (often) holds a pointer to the first element of the string. (If you meant the `c_str()` member function, then that could be done, but it's not a particularly clear and readable syntax.)

Comment: Side note: when using small string optimization (SSO), std::string does not hold a pointer to the string's first element. All characters are stored in-place. Also `c_str()` might cause copying. I think `.data()` is what you might be referring to.

Comment: @Kostas True enough. I added an acknowledgement of that, but I don't think explaining SSO would add enough value to the answer, when compared to the potential for confusion.

Comment: @Kostas I picked `c_str` because its name is similar to `str`. Regardless, `c_str()` and `data()` perform the same function as of C++11.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::begin()` returns an iterator to the first character of the string.  Iterators are a generalization of pointers, and act as the glue between containers and algorithms so the two can be decoupled.